# How to find the Kronecker product row by row between two dimensional matrices?

Tags: c++

I have the following Matrices x1 and x2

```
int x1[3][4] ={  
   {0, 1, 2, 3} ,   
   {4, 5, 6, 7} ,   
   {8, 9, 10, 11}};

int x2[3][4]= {{0, 4, 5, 1} ,   
              {4, 9, 4, 3} ,   
              {8, 4, 1, 14}};
```

I would like to know how to do kronecker product row by row some thing like that:

kronecker_results ={{x1_row1⊗x2_row1},{x1_row2⊗x2_row2},{x1_row3⊗x2_row3}};

without using kronecker product in Eigen

currently I am using for loops to do Kronecker product but I still face problems in figuring out a way to group the results as shown in kronecker_results matrix.

K index can not cover the dimension of the kronecker product ..is there a way to achieve that?

```
int kronecker_x[3][16];
    for (int i = 0; i <3 ; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
                {
                kronecker_x[i][k] = x1[i][j] * x2[i][k];
                
                }
```

Comment: Shouldn't the Kronecker product be a `9x16` matrix? Can you please show the result of the operation on the inputs?

Comment: since every row in  kronecker_x should be kronecker product of the two rows in x1 and x2 then the dimension of  kronecker_x is 3x16

Comment: Could you show an example row of the result? Also, please add the definition of Kronecker product to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product

Since both x1 and x2 are 3x4, then final Kronecker product will be a 9x16 matrix.

To get 3x16 matrix, you would have to only Kronecker multiply a single row from x1 with the full x2... and ignore the additional rows from x1. Your final matrix for any single row from x1 would be:

```
{{x1r1⊗x2r1},{x1r1⊗x2r2},{x1r1⊗x2r3}}
```

which expanded is:

```
{
    {
        {x1r1c1⊗x2r1},{x1r1c2⊗x2r1},{x1r1c3⊗x2r1},{x1r1c4⊗x2r1}
    },
    {
        {x1r1c1⊗x2r2},{x1r1c2⊗x2r2},{x1r1c3⊗x2r2},{x1r1c4⊗x2r2}
    },
    {
        {x1r1c1⊗x2r3},{x1r1c2⊗x2r3},{x1r1c3⊗x2r3},{x1r1c4⊗x2r3}
    }
}
```

Your function for doing this would look more like:

```
int rowIndex = 0;
int colIndex = 0;
int kronecker_x1r1[3][16];
for (int i = 0; i <3 ; i++)
{
    colIndex = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
        {
            kronecker_x1r1[i][colIndex] = x1[rowIndex][j] * x2[i][k];
            colIndex++;
        }
    }
}
```

The full Kronecker product would be put together something like:

```
int kRowIndex = 0;
int kColIndex = 0;
int kroneckerProduct[9][16];
for (int i = 0; i < 3 ; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        kColIndex = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
        {
            for (int l = 0; l < 4; l++)
            {
                kroneckerProduct[kRowIndex][kColIndex] = x1[i][k] * x2[j][l];
                kColIndex++;
            }
        }
        kRowIndex++;
    }    
}
```